# What Perl glob expression matches all the files that look like /home/test-N.txt?

Tags: perl, glob

I am a beginner to Perl syntax and have a basic wildcard question. I am looking for an expression that would allow me to retrieve all of the following files.

```
/home/test-1.txt  
/home/test-2.txt  
/home/test-3.txt
```

I am just interested in the actual wildcard expression, not the file I/O.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`</home/test-*.txt>` should glob the files you need.

`glob("/home/test-*.txt")` does the same thing.

Here's a [short globbing tutorial](http://perl.about.com/od/filesystem/qt/perlglob.htm).

Comment: If you are using something other than `/` to delimit your regex, you need to prefix the regex with m. Also, you might need to escape your /s.

Comment: Thomas, there's no regular expression involved here. It's a glob, which uses shell-like wildcard syntax, not regular expressions.

Comment: `glob("/home/test-*.txt")` is another way of saying the same thing.